# I did not ask a question but how it's showing under my account

Tags: support, questions, reputation-history, automatic-deletion

[image]

[How to determine if choose file button is set?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30684033/how-to-determine-if-choose-file-button-is-set/30684086#30684086)

I did not ask this question. But it's showing under my account's Reputation section with -10 :(

As the link is broken I can't see actually what happened!

Does it indicate my account is hacked?

What is the remedy?

Comment: no but you voted

Comment: Does it mean if I vote a question asked by someone else and that question is deleted by admin, I get -8 ? Do you have a link where I can learn more about it. Thanks

Comment: Did you answer this question? I think you lose the rep from your answer if the question is deleted.

Comment: @BSMP: Yes, he answered a really bad question, which was down-voted and closed. When there was no longer an upvoted answer, it was pruned shortly after.

Comment: [How do I read the history of my reputation?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/139614/165773)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You had an answer on that question that'd received one upvote (+10) and a downvote (-2). The question having remained closed for 14 days, with a -2 score and not containing a positively net scoring answer (yours being a net of 0) - qualified for deletion by an automatic process to avoid cluttering of the site.

When a question is removed - so are its answers. Since the post was less than a certain age threshold - the voting for everything on that question and any answer(s) get reversed - hence what you're seeing.

See https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/92006/ for further information.

Comment: I see. Thanks for the explanation.